# ransack + AASM: ArgumentError wrong number of arguments (given 1, expected 0)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ransack, aasm

I faced the following error when running filtering using `ransack`:

```
ArgumentError wrong number of arguments (given 1, expected 0)
```

and stack trace is showing this:

```
object.ransack(query_params)
```

When dug deeper I have found that the error appears in `aasm_create_scope` method from the `aasm` gem.

```
query_params = {accepted: "value"}
```

What could go wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that `accepted` is a scope provided by `aasm` which doesn't accept arguments. Ransack doesn't send an argument when the value is `true` or ignore the scope when it is set to `false`.

```
{ accepted: "true" } || { accepted: "false" }
```

would only make sense. Any other value will raise that error.